# XSL to generate UUIDs for users & replace for their manager references accordingly

Tags: java, xml, xslt, uuid

I have this below XML with `id` and `managerid` self referenced to each other with many ids to one `managerid` and I would need to convert their ids to **`UUID`** based ids to the target XML. I'm using Java `uuid class` via extension function. I'm struck with `maaping genrated uuid` to `managerid` in target XML and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<userlist>
    <user>
        <id>1</id>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>2</id>
        <managerid>1</managerid>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>3</id>
        <managerid>1</managerid>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>4</id>
        <managerid>2</managerid>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>5</id>
        <managerid>3</managerid>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>6</id>
        <managerid>1</managerid>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>7</id>
        <managerid>2</managerid>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>8</id>
        <managerid>3</managerid>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>9</id>
        <managerid>3</managerid>
    </user>
    <user>
        <id>10</id>
        <managerid>1</managerid>
    </user>
</userlist>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:uuid="java:java.util.UUID">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="id" match="id" use="."/>

    <!-- identity transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="id">
    <xsl:variable name="uid" select="uuid:randomUUID()"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="$uid"/>           
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="managerid">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('id', .)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very poorly worded. If I understand correctly, managers are also users. Therefore, you want to replace each user's `id` with a UUID **and** - if that user is also a manager - replace the corresponding `managerid` with the **same** UUID.

This could be accomplished by:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:uuid="java:java.util.UUID">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="new-ids">
    <xsl:for-each select="/userlist/user">
        <new-id old-id="{id}">
            <xsl:value-of select="uuid:randomUUID()"/>
        </new-id>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:key name="new-id" match="new-id" use="@old-id" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="id | managerid">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('new-id', ., $new-ids)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I appreciate it and its working as expected. sorry for my wording but you understood it correct.  I would expect to map their ids for 200,000 users in the incoming XMLs. Is it good idea to put all of those ids in variable is it good to process them in the memory?

Comment: I tried with muenchian technique and it is not working.  Can you help me this below logic ?  <xsl:key name="equal" match="id" use="."/>         <xsl:template match="id[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('equal', .)[last()]))]">  <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('new-id', ., $new-ids)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

Comment: Looking to handle duplicates in the given XML, user is treated as duplicate if id matches with other user elements.

Comment: @Samdalton This seems to have nothing with the question above - I suggest you post a new one.