# XSL to omit duplicates while generating GUID output for user and manager

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the below `user` XML nodes which have an `id` and `managerid` relationship, as self referenced to each other with many `id`s to one `managerid` and I would need to generate UUID based ids to the target XML.  However I already got this below solution to generate UUID for them. I got duplicate `user` nodes with the same `id` and `managerid`.  I will need to select only one user node. I'm stuck with mapping generated uuid to managerid in target XML and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<userlist>
<user>
    <id>1</id>
</user>
<user>
    <id>2</id>
    <managerid>1</managerid>
</user>
<user>
    <id>2</id>
    <managerid>1</managerid>
</user>
<user>
    <id>2</id>
    <managerid>1</managerid>
</user>
<user>
    <id>3</id>
    <managerid>1</managerid>
</user>
<user>
    <id>3</id>
    <managerid>1</managerid>
</user>
<user>
    <id>4</id>
    <managerid>2</managerid>
</user>
<user>
    <id>4</id>
    <managerid>2</managerid>
</user>
<user>
    <id>5</id>
    <managerid>3</managerid>
</user>
<user>
    <id>6</id>
    <managerid>1</managerid>
</user>
<user>
    <id>7</id>
    <managerid>2</managerid>
</user>
<user>
    <id>8</id>
    <managerid>3</managerid>
</user>
<user>
    <id>9</id>
    <managerid>3</managerid>
</user>
<user>
    <id>9</id>
    <managerid>3</managerid>
</user>
<user>
    <id>10</id>
    <managerid>1</managerid>
</user>
<user>
    <id>10</id>
    <managerid>1</managerid>
</user>
```

This below XSL works correctly if input XML doesn't have duplicates.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"   xmlns:uuid="java:java.util.UUID">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="new-ids">
    <xsl:for-each select="/userlist/user">
        <new-id old-id="{id}">
          <xsl:value-of select="uuid:randomUUID()"/>
         </new-id>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:key name="new-id" match="new-id" use="@old-id" />

 <!-- identity transform -->

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="id | managerid">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:value-of select="key('new-id', ., $new-ids)"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

current output:

```
     <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
     <userlist>
         <user>
            <id>2fde0216-c017-4a2c-8372-5a0fd338a4ac</id>
         </user>
       <user>
         <id>06d183b9-7dc6-4078-a77f-b32fb526fa61 01a9fc38-2f32-459d-88d9-
             32cbde8bc570 87622536-eb87-408b-bb31-f3599d4fb286</id>
         <managerid>2fde0216-c017-4a2c-8372-5a0fd338a4ac</managerid>
  </user>
  <user>
    <id>06d183b9-7dc6-4078-a77f-b32fb526fa61 01a9fc38-2f32-459d-88d9-32cbde8bc570 87622536-eb87-408b-bb31-f3599d4fb286</id>
    <managerid>2fde0216-c017-4a2c-8372-5a0fd338a4ac</managerid>
  </user>
  <user>
    <id>06d183b9-7dc6-4078-a77f-b32fb526fa61 01a9fc38-2f32-459d-88d9-32cbde8bc570 87622536-eb87-408b-bb31-f3599d4fb286</id>
    <managerid>2fde0216-c017-4a2c-8372-5a0fd338a4ac</managerid>
  </user>
  <user>
    <id>3a4785d7-a878-46cb-96ff-772d127fd292 fa972787-47d3-405e-acb3-12fa1540caff</id>
    <managerid>2fde0216-c017-4a2c-8372-5a0fd338a4ac</managerid>
  </user>
  <user>
    <id>3a4785d7-a878-46cb-96ff-772d127fd292 fa972787-47d3-405e-acb3-12fa1540caff</id>
    <managerid>2fde0216-c017-4a2c-8372-5a0fd338a4ac</managerid>
  </user>
  <user>
    <id>e075096d-87b7-400c-b8ab-d9e02d8496cf e5381986-c788-4c1a-9d78-e965676da26c</id>
    <managerid>06d183b9-7dc6-4078-a77f-b32fb526fa61 01a9fc38-2f32-459d-88d9-32cbde8bc570 87622536-eb87-408b-bb31-f3599d4fb286</managerid>
  </user>
  <user>
    <id>e075096d-87b7-400c-b8ab-d9e02d8496cf e5381986-c788-4c1a-9d78-e965676da26c</id>
    <managerid>06d183b9-7dc6-4078-a77f-b32fb526fa61 01a9fc38-2f32-459d-88d9-32cbde8bc570 87622536-eb87-408b-bb31-f3599d4fb286</managerid>
  </user>
  <user>
    <id>7347f53a-0853-4995-810f-9c59b8cbb01f</id>
    <managerid>3a4785d7-a878-46cb-96ff-772d127fd292 fa972787-47d3-405e-acb3-12fa1540caff</managerid>
  </user>
  <user>
    <id>c2925611-f04e-4bc1-a887-9c117f933433</id>
    <managerid>2fde0216-c017-4a2c-8372-5a0fd338a4ac</managerid>
  </user>
  <user>
    <id>c843fe6e-399a-4f8c-9efc-8b864cd87a4c</id>
    <managerid>06d183b9-7dc6-4078-a77f-b32fb526fa61 01a9fc38-2f32-459d-88d9-32cbde8bc570 87622536-eb87-408b-bb31-f3599d4fb286</managerid>
  </user>
  <user>
    <id>e778eb2e-8989-4e9d-a0b3-4ee3b25cce07</id>
    <managerid>3a4785d7-a878-46cb-96ff-772d127fd292 fa972787-47d3-405e-acb3-12fa1540caff</managerid>
  </user>
  <user>
    <id>68cf6663-90b9-465a-b30d-a6305d715b64 de7cb144-a63f-4302-9ea5-60ff4646bd75</id>
    <managerid>3a4785d7-a878-46cb-96ff-772d127fd292 fa972787-47d3-405e-acb3-12fa1540caff</managerid>
  </user>
  <user>
    <id>68cf6663-90b9-465a-b30d-a6305d715b64 de7cb144-a63f-4302-9ea5-60ff4646bd75</id>
    <managerid>3a4785d7-a878-46cb-96ff-772d127fd292 fa972787-47d3-405e-acb3-12fa1540caff</managerid>
  </user>
  <user>
    <id>a9bb4d6c-534a-489b-b2ea-6c31346356eb 33220966-dfee-476b-bc50-6fc6e9fd28ab</id>
    <managerid>2fde0216-c017-4a2c-8372-5a0fd338a4ac</managerid>
  </user>
  <user>
    <id>a9bb4d6c-534a-489b-b2ea-6c31346356eb 33220966-dfee-476b-bc50-6fc6e9fd28ab</id>
    <managerid>2fde0216-c017-4a2c-8372-5a0fd338a4ac</managerid>
  </user>
</userlist>
```

Comment: Can you show your expected output please?

Answer (score 0):

*Previous answer: [XSL to generate UUIDs for users & replace for their manager references accordingly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29739320/xsl-to-generate-uuids-for-users-replace-for-their-manager-references-according)*

---

How about:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:uuid="java:java.util.UUID"
exclude-result-prefixes="uuid">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- remove duplicates + generate a UUID for each distinct user -->
<xsl:variable name="new-list">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="/userlist/user" group-by="id">
        <user new-id="{uuid:randomUUID()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]/*"/>
        </user>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/userlist">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$new-list"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- replace existing ids with corresponding UUIDs -->
<xsl:key name="user-by-old-id" match="user" use="id" />
<xsl:template match="id | managerid">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('user-by-old-id', .)/@new-id"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@new-id"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```